# Specjour and Spork Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests, specjour

I am using Specjour v0.4.1 for full test suite runs and preloading a rails app to run individual specs with Spork and Guard. Specjour uses multiple workers (usually 4) to run tests simultaneously.

How can I pass the preloaded application to each one of these workers? As specjour continues to load the application for each worker.

Note: `rspec spec/models/example_spec.rb --drb` is used to force rspec to use the preloaded application.

I've forked specjour and tried to push the `--drb` flag to each worker using several methods with no success. Any insight would appreciated. Thanks!

Note: `hooks.rb` configuration seems promising (mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/sandro/specjour)), however, documentation is extremely slim.

Comment: How did you solve your issue at the end?